# How can I write ORDER BY LENGTH(test) DESC as Criteria query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa, criteria-api

How can I write ORDER BY LENGTH(test) DESC, LENGTH(test2) DESC, test3 DESC as JPA Criteria query?

Answer (score 3):

See following example in [JPA Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html).

```
CriteriaQuery<Pet> cq = cb.createQuery(Pet.class);
Root<Pet> pet = cq.from(Pet.class);
cq.select(pet);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(pet.get(Pet_.birthday)));
```

I assume your Table is Table1 then

```
CriteriaQuery<Table1> cq = cb.createQuery(Table1.class);
Root<Table1> table1= cq.from(Table1.class);
cq.select(table1);
cq.orderBy(cb.desc(table1.get(Table1_.test.length())));
```

I added .length() to your column name.